# I want to get list of reminders of particular user id only. What should I do?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two tables in SQLite database, one is user table and other is time reminder table. After the user logins, he should get only his reminders list, not others' list. I am using where clause in the select query in the database class but it is not working. Please help.

```
// create table sql query
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER
        + "("
        + COLUMN_USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + COLUMN_USER_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT," 
        + COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT" 
        + ")";

 String CREATE_REMINDERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_REMINDERS +
            "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + USER_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIME + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_REPEAT + " BOOLEAN,"
            + KEY_REPEAT_NO + " INTEGER,"
            + KEY_REPEAT_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ACTIVE + " BOOLEAN" +
            "FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES TABLE_USER(COLUMN_USER_ID)" +
            ")";

 // Getting all Reminders
public List<Reminder> getAllReminders(){
    List<Reminder> reminderList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Select all Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REMINDERS + "where" + USER_ID + "=" +  COLUMN_USER_ID;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? What are your exact symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass userID as a variable to the function. And use it in query

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REMINDERS + "where" + USER_ID + "=" +  mUserId;
```

Final code :

```
public List<Reminder> getAllReminders(int mUserId){
    List<Reminder> reminderList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Select all Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_REMINDERS + "where" + USER_ID + "=" +  mUserId;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
}
```

Comment: what is being stored in mUserId? @NileshDeokar

Comment: after user login you must be getting his userId from somewhere right? just pass same to this `getAllReminders()` function.